# Expressions in Tim Minchin's "Cont."

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

In his song "Cont.", Tim Minchin uses two expressions I cannot find in a dictionary: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmTexiEZmL8

Can somebody explain the meanings?

1. "..., who lean on their horn..." (5:34)
2. "talk camply" (6:04)

Answer (score 3):

To "lean on your horn" is to sound your car horn, usually aggressively.

"Camp" in this context means "effeminate". To "talk camply" is to talk in an effeminate manner.

Comment: To "lean on your horn" is a very common usage in American English. I don't think it needs a source. And in American slang, ["camp"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=camp) can mean a variety of things. But if you look at the actual lyrics, it's clearly the gay meaning of "camp", which I don't believe is quite the same as  "effeminate", but it's close enough for government work.